# Return the item name not object Object

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have a list of page elements that I am trying to validate are being displayed on the screen.

I would like to output to the console the element name I am looking for however when I do that I am just getting `object Object`.

```
    var detailElements = [disabledRuleWarning, detailsLabel, detailsHide,
    nameLabel, nameField, ruleActive, groupLabel, threatTypeLabel,
    threatTypeDropdown, descLabel, descField, tagsLabel, tagsField,
    severityLabel, actionsLabel, addAction];

    it(TestSuiteName + 'TC5_Verify Details Elements are displayed', function(){
    console.log('TC5 Verify Details Elements are displayed');
    DetectionRules.newRuleButton.click();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    detailElements.forEach((item) => {
        console.log('Checking for item: ' + item);
        expect(item.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    });
    DetectionRules.deleteRule.click();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand items of a `detailElements` array are `ElementFinder` objects - the results of `element(by.smth(...))` calls.

`ElementFinder` string representation is not something you want to see on the console. Instead I would suggest using an object/mapping instead of an array:

```
var detailElements = {
    'disabledRuleWarning': disabledRuleWarning,
    // ...
    'addAction': addAction
}
```

Then, you can output the keys of `detailElements` on the console why operating the elements which are values of the `detailElements` object:

```
Object.keys(detailElements).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log('Checking for item: ' + key);
    expect(detailElements[key].isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @alecxe I will give this a shot as soon as I get my environment set back up.